# Ubuntu 20.04 Sennheisser Momentum TW 2 bluetooth connection

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 20.04, headphones

I can't connect my Sennheisser Momentum TW 2 Headphones by bluetooth. Android and Windows work fine but in Ubuntu it gets into a loop. I just hear again and again 'power on, connected'. If I just use one earbud it connects fine but no a2dp_sink profile can be activated. I've tried many answers with no success.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is posted in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256775/bluetooth-earbuds-constantly-reconnecting-sennheiser-momentum-tw-2). It says:

As a work around you disable AVRCP entirely. The earbuds should work fine just without touch controls. Edit the file /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service and add --noplugin=avrcp to the end of line 9.

E.g.

```
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth service
Documentation=man:bluetoothd(8)
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.bluez
ExecStart=/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=avrcp
NotifyAccess=main
#WatchdogSec=10
#Restart=on-failure
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
LimitNPROC=1
ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full

[Install]
WantedBy=bluetooth.target
Alias=dbus-org.bluez.service
```