# Bluetooth earbuds constantly reconnecting (Sennheiser Momentum TW 2)

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, connection

i'm running currently Kubuntu 20.04 and trying to connect new earbuds (Sennheiser Momentum true wireless 2) but i get the earbuds connected and after a second disconnected, then it tries to connect again, and so on.
I tried to connect other earbuds (Samsung Gear IconX2018) and it works without problems.
The same is with bluetooth dongle on PC and laptop bluetooth. Runned also Win7 portable from usb stick and it found a driver from MS and connection was OK.

bluetootsctl output:

```
 Agent registered
[CHG] Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:09 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 MOMENTUM TW 2
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 RSSI: -66
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 TxPower: -12
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 UUIDs: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 UUIDs: 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 UUIDs: 0000fdce-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[NEW] Device B0:FA:EB:2F:9E:3D B0FAEB2F9E3C
[NEW] Device D0:20:92:CF:BE:8B fenix 3
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 RSSI: -93
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 RSSI: -59
[NEW] Device F4:7D:EF:FF:9E:87 Galaxy Fitⓔ (9E87)
[CHG] Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:09 Discovering: no
[CHG] Device F4:7D:EF:FF:9E:87 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device D0:20:92:CF:BE:8B RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device B0:FA:EB:2F:9E:3D RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 TxPower is nil
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 RSSI is nil
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 Modalias: usb:v1377p7001d0480
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 UUIDs: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 UUIDs: 0000eb03-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 Paired: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 Trusted: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9 Connected: no
```

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046d:0843 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C930e
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 046d:c333 Logitech, Inc. Gaming Keyboard G610
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 003: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 010 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

journalctl -u bluetooth | tail:

```
 bluetoothd[965]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
bluetoothd[965]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_88_BD_45_D1_39_35/sep2/fd0: fd(58) ready
bluetoothd[965]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for 00:1B:66:BC:2E:F9: Device or resource busy
bluetoothd[965]: No reply to Start request
bluetoothd[965]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
bluetoothd[965]: No reply to Start request
bluetoothd[965]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
bluetoothd[965]: connect error: Connection refused (111)
bluetoothd[965]: connect error: Connection refused (111)
bluetoothd[965]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
bluetoothd[965]: No reply to Start request
bluetoothd[965]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
bluetoothd[965]: No reply to Start request
bluetoothd[965]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
bluetoothd[965]: No reply to Start request
bluetoothd[965]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
bluetoothd[965]: No reply to Start request
bluetoothd[965]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
```

systemctl status bluetooth:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-07-06 20:25:17 CEST; 15h ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 965 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 14263)
     Memory: 3.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─965 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

bluetoothd[965]: connect error: Connection refused (111)
bluetoothd[965]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
bluetoothd[965]: No reply to Start request
bluetoothd[965]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
bluetoothd[965]: No reply to Start request
bluetoothd[965]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
bluetoothd[965]: No reply to Start request
bluetoothd[965]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
bluetoothd[965]: No reply to Start request
bluetoothd[965]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
```

dpkg -l | grep blue

```
ii  bluedevil                                     4:5.18.4.1-0ubuntu1                         amd64        KDE Bluetooth stack
ii  bluez                                         5.53-0ubuntu3                               amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-cups                                    5.53-0ubuntu3                               amd64        Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
ii  bluez-obexd                                   5.53-0ubuntu3                               amd64        bluez obex daemon
ii  libbluetooth3:amd64                           5.53-0ubuntu3                               amd64        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  libkf5bluezqt-data                            5.68.0-0ubuntu1                             all          data files for bluez-qt
ii  libkf5bluezqt6:amd64                          5.68.0-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Qt wrapper for bluez
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                   1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.3                        amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  qml-module-org-kde-bluezqt:amd64              5.68.0-0ubuntu1                             amd64        QML wrapper for bluez
```

Any help and tipps are apreciated.
If som additional info needed, please tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this issue as well and just spent many hours attempting to solve it. I've narrowed it down to an issue with the AVRCP profile (controls the media buttons).

As a work around you disable AVRCP entirely. The earbuds should work fine just without touch controls. Edit the file `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service` and add `--noplugin=avrcp` to the end of line 9 (`ExecStart`).

E.g.

```
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth service
Documentation=man:bluetoothd(8)
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.bluez
ExecStart=/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=avrcp
NotifyAccess=main
#WatchdogSec=10
#Restart=on-failure
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
LimitNPROC=1
ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full

[Install]
WantedBy=bluetooth.target
Alias=dbus-org.bluez.service
```

Comment: Great! This works! I have not thought at all of using the control buttons, for me it is nessesary only to use it as regular earphones to listen to music or when i'm watching webinars or so on, so for me this is a sloution. Howewer it seems that it can not be uesed for talking (not showing in capture devices), but maybe later it will be fixed with PA bluetooth or bluez updates. Thanks again!

Comment: FWIW, my Momentum TW 2 failed in a different way on Ubuntu 20.04, but this solution seems to have fixed the problem for me as well.

Comment: This solution fixed the problem for me as well. But the strange thing is that, once I disconnect my Momentum TW 2, I cannot get it reconnected again. I needed to remove the device and pair it again.

Comment: I have Momentum TW 2 as well. I got it connecting using this answer. However, the audio output doesn't actually go to the buds. I am toggling everything in Sound settings and it makes no difference.

Comment: I found a work around, here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232159/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound-out-of-bluetooth-headphones/1233846#comment2227286_1233846

Comment: It worked for me, but I had to restart the bluetooth service and sysctl daemon for the changes to take effect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue has been fixed in Bluez 5.55.

From the [changelog](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/commit/5a180f2ec9edfacafd95e5fed20d36fe8e077f07):

```
Fix issue with handling AVRCP notification events.
Fix issue with handling AVRCP list player attributes.
Fix issue with handling AVRCP category 1 player settings.
Fix issue with handling AVRCP media player passthrough bitmask.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and Bluez is at 5.48.
Rebuilding [bluez/mainline](https://github.com/bluez/bluez) (`c96d5ec7aafc` at the time of writing) and just using the generated `bluetoothd` binary in place of `/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd` fixed the issue without using the `--noplugin=avrcp` flag.
I recommend using `make install` anyway tho to avoid any possible conflict.

I can also confirm that playback buttons (pause, forward, backward) detection works and are correctly handled by Rhythmbox.

Is it possible to use the microphone as well setting the device as `headset_head_unit` (see `man pactl` for more info), the audio quality sucks big time this way, but it's better than nothing (I guess?).

Building bluez from source is pretty straightforward, just follow the README, let's hope the package will be up-streamed ASAP anyway.

Comment: I downloaded the files from github, unzipped it, opened terminal and went to that directory. I ran "make install" and it throws an error. "make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop." I have Ubuntu 20.04.